# npm run demo doesn't pointing to demo

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, dotenv

I have two different environments with named `.env.development`, `.env.production`, and common `.env` also.

`.env.development` looks like this,

```
TEST_LABEL=Development
```

`.env.production` looks like this,

```
TEST_LABEL=Production
```

`.env` looks like this,

```
TEST_LABEL=ENV
```

And here is my `babel.config.js`,

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
      ["module:react-native-dotenv",
        {
          "moduleName": "@env"
        },]
    ]
  };
};
```

this is the scripts in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "development": "NODE_ENV=development expo start",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production expo start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest"
},
```

And this is how I used it in my `Homescreen.js`

```
import {TEST_LABEL} from "@env"
...
<Text>{TEST_LABEL}</Text>
```

And this displays always `Development` even I run the production env

I run the app like `npm run development` for development environment, `npm run production` for production environment.

I am using [react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv)

Here is the Project structure snapshot,

[image]

Comment: Have u tried toggling the caching off?

Comment: Yes, I have tried

Comment: what is the value of TEST_LABEL in the common `.env`?

Comment: I updated my answer, clearing the cache solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [issue](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/74) and it says the only supported envs are `development`, `production`, and `test`. If you want to use other env names you can use the [experimental feature](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv#experimental-feature) APP_ENV

```
    "demo": "APP_ENV=demo expo start",
    "local": "APP_ENV=local expo start",
```

and I think `.local` files are loaded by [default](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/76)

**UDPATE**

I tested your config and it looks like this [issue](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/issues/75#issuecomment-728055969) is the reason the value is not updating, adding `-c` to your commands clears the cache and load the correct env values

```
    "development": "NODE_ENV=development expo start -c",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production expo start -c",
```

Comment: I have changed the file names to `.env.production` and `.env.development`, and changed the script also, Still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Hi, Do you know how to build APK/IPA file based on environment, like generating production APK or generating development APK